# Catching an ESC press when editing a QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

How can I catch if the user edits a `QTableWidgetItem` and aborts it via pressing `ESC`? I process the content of the respective item by catching `QTableWidget::cellDoubleClicked`, and I know when something has been changed by listening to `QTableWidget::cellChanged`. But when the user presses `ESC`, I don't know it.

I tried to install an event filter on the `QTableWidget`, but it only catches key presses that the widget itself receives – the editor seems to be another thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a delegate and use your [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#eventFilter), the following code is an example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QTableWidget>

#include <QDebug>

class TableWidgetDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * object, QEvent * event){
        QWidget *editor = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(object);
        if(editor && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
            if(static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event)->key() == Qt::Key_Escape){
                qDebug()<<"escape";
            }
        }
        return QStyledItemDelegate::eventFilter(editor, event);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableWidget w(6, 4);
    w.setItemDelegate(new TableWidgetDelegate);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the incredibly fast and perfectly complete answer :-)